# How do I interface my ESP32 board with my 3.5" TFT Screen

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, tft

I've bought an ESP32 board [from here](https://www.az-delivery.de/en/products/esp32-d1-r32-board) and a 3.5" TFT Screen [from here](https://uk.banggood.com/3_5-Inch-TFT-Color-Display-Screen-Module-320-X-480-Support-UNO-Mega2560-Geekcreit-for-Arduino-products-that-work-with-official-Arduino-boards-p-1022298.html?cur_warehouse=CN). The ESP32 board has an UNO type layout so I thought it would work with the screen which is designed to  plug in and play with Arduino UNOs.

However upon plugging the board and shield together (they fit perfectly, each pin goes in a corresponding slot), loading one of the example scripts (provided on the 3.5" Screen .rar download on the page), set Arduino to use ESP32 Development Board on COM3 (my usual settings for the ESP32) and uploading the code I just get a white screen on the TFT.

Is there some accommodation that I have to make because my board is not an UNO but instead a ESP32, i.e. is the pin layout different so maybe I'll need to wire this manually?

I've included the pin out diagrams below:

[image: TFT shield pinout]
[image: TFT shield pinout instructions]
[image: ESP32 pinout]

**Arduino Sketch Code:**

```
#include <MCUFRIEND_kbv.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>    // Core graphics library


// wiring with UNO or Mega2560:
//--------------POWER Pins--------------------------------
//   5V  connects to DC 5V
//   GND connects to Ground
//   3V3 do not need to connect(NC)
//--------------LCD Display Pins--------------------------
//   LCD_RD   connects to Analog pin A0  
//   LCD_WR   connects to Analog pin A1  
//   LCD_RS   connects to Analog pin A2  
//   LCD_CS   connects to Analog pin A3  
//   LCD_RST  connects to Analog pin A4  
//   LCD_D0   connects to digital pin 8  
//   LCD_D1   connects to digital pin 9  
//   LCD_D2   connects to digital pin 2
//   LCD_D3   connects to digital pin 3
//   LCD_D4   connects to digital pin 4
//   LCD_D5   connects to digital pin 5
//   LCD_D6   connects to digital pin 6
//   LCD_D7   connects to digital pin 7
//--------------SD-card fuction Pins ----------------------
//This Connection Only for UNO, Do not support Mega2560
//because they use different Hardware-SPI Pins
//SD_SS    connects to digital pin 10
//SD_DI    connects to digital pin 11
//SD_DO    connects to digital pin 12
//SD_SCK   connects to digital pin 13


#define LCD_RESET A4 // Can alternately just connect to Arduino's reset pin
#define LCD_CS A3   // Chip Select goes to Analog 3
#define LCD_CD A2  // Command/Data goes to Analog 2
#define LCD_WR A1  // LCD Write goes to Analog 1
#define LCD_RD A0 // LCD Read goes to Analog 0

// Assign human-readable names to some common 16-bit color values:
#define  BLACK   0x0000
#define BLUE    0x001F
#define RED     0xF800
#define GREEN   0x07E0
#define CYAN    0x07FF
#define MAGENTA 0xF81F
#define YELLOW  0xFFE0
#define WHITE   0xFFFF


MCUFRIEND_kbv tft;




unsigned long testFillScreen() {
  unsigned long start = micros();
  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
  tft.fillScreen(RED);
  tft.fillScreen(GREEN);
  tft.fillScreen(BLUE);
  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
  return micros() - start;
}

unsigned long testText() {
  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
  unsigned long start = micros();
  tft.setCursor(0, 0);
  tft.setTextColor(WHITE);  tft.setTextSize(1);
  tft.println("Hello World!");
  tft.setTextColor(YELLOW); tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.println(1234.56);
  tft.setTextColor(RED);    tft.setTextSize(3);
  tft.println(0xDEADBEEF, HEX);
  tft.println();
  tft.setTextColor(GREEN);
  tft.setTextSize(5);
  tft.println("Groop");
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.println("I implore thee,");
  tft.setTextSize(1);
  tft.println("my foonting turlingdromes.");
  tft.println("And hooptiously drangle me");
  tft.println("with crinkly bindlewurdles,");
  tft.println("Or I will rend thee");
  tft.println("in the gobberwarts");
  tft.println("with my blurglecruncheon,");
  tft.println("see if I don't!");
  return micros() - start;
}

unsigned long testLines(uint16_t color) {
  unsigned long start, t;
  int           x1, y1, x2, y2,
                w = tft.width(),
                h = tft.height();

  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);

  x1 = y1 = 0;
  y2    = h - 1;
  start = micros();
  for(x2=0; x2<w; x2+=6) tft.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
  x2    = w - 1;
  for(y2=0; y2<h; y2+=6) tft.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
  t     = micros() - start; // fillScreen doesn't count against timing

  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);

  x1    = w - 1;
  y1    = 0;
  y2    = h - 1;
  start = micros();
  for(x2=0; x2<w; x2+=6) tft.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
  x2    = 0;
  for(y2=0; y2<h; y2+=6) tft.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
  t    += micros() - start;

  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);

  x1    = 0;
  y1    = h - 1;
  y2    = 0;
  start = micros();
  for(x2=0; x2<w; x2+=6) tft.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
  x2    = w - 1;
  for(y2=0; y2<h; y2+=6) tft.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
  t    += micros() - start;

  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);

  x1    = w - 1;
  y1    = h - 1;
  y2    = 0;
  start = micros();
  for(x2=0; x2<w; x2+=6) tft.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
  x2    = 0;
  for(y2=0; y2<h; y2+=6) tft.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);

  return micros() - start;
}

unsigned long testFastLines(uint16_t color1, uint16_t color2) {
  unsigned long start;
  int           x, y, w = tft.width(), h = tft.height();

  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
  start = micros();
  for(y=0; y<h; y+=5) tft.drawFastHLine(0, y, w, color1);
  for(x=0; x<w; x+=5) tft.drawFastVLine(x, 0, h, color2);

  return micros() - start;
}

unsigned long testRects(uint16_t color) {
  unsigned long start;
  int           n, i, i2,
                cx = tft.width()  / 2,
                cy = tft.height() / 2;

  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
  n     = min(tft.width(), tft.height());
  start = micros();
  for(i=2; i<n; i+=6) {
    i2 = i / 2;
    tft.drawRect(cx-i2, cy-i2, i, i, color);
  }

  return micros() - start;
}

unsigned long testFilledRects(uint16_t color1, uint16_t color2) {
  unsigned long start, t = 0;
  int           n, i, i2,
                cx = tft.width()  / 2 - 1,
                cy = tft.height() / 2 - 1;

  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
  n = min(tft.width(), tft.height());
  for(i=n; i>0; i-=6) {
    i2    = i / 2;
    start = micros();
    tft.fillRect(cx-i2, cy-i2, i, i, color1);
    t    += micros() - start;
    // Outlines are not included in timing results
    tft.drawRect(cx-i2, cy-i2, i, i, color2);
  }

  return t;
}

unsigned long testFilledCircles(uint8_t radius, uint16_t color) {
  unsigned long start;
  int x, y, w = tft.width(), h = tft.height(), r2 = radius * 2;

  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
  start = micros();
  for(x=radius; x<w; x+=r2) {
    for(y=radius; y<h; y+=r2) {
      tft.fillCircle(x, y, radius, color);
    }
  }

  return micros() - start;
}

unsigned long testCircles(uint8_t radius, uint16_t color) {
  unsigned long start;
  int           x, y, r2 = radius * 2,
                w = tft.width()  + radius,
                h = tft.height() + radius;

  // Screen is not cleared for this one -- this is
  // intentional and does not affect the reported time.
  start = micros();
  for(x=0; x<w; x+=r2) {
    for(y=0; y<h; y+=r2) {
      tft.drawCircle(x, y, radius, color);
    }
  }

  return micros() - start;
}

unsigned long testTriangles() {
  unsigned long start;
  int           n, i, cx = tft.width()  / 2 - 1,
                      cy = tft.height() / 2 - 1;

  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
  n     = min(cx, cy);
  start = micros();
  for(i=0; i<n; i+=5) {
    tft.drawTriangle(
      cx    , cy - i, // peak
      cx - i, cy + i, // bottom left
      cx + i, cy + i, // bottom right
      tft.color565(0, 0, i));
  }

  return micros() - start;
}

unsigned long testFilledTriangles() {
  unsigned long start, t = 0;
  int           i, cx = tft.width()  / 2 - 1,
                   cy = tft.height() / 2 - 1;

  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
  start = micros();
  for(i=min(cx,cy); i>10; i-=5) {
    start = micros();
    tft.fillTriangle(cx, cy - i, cx - i, cy + i, cx + i, cy + i,
      tft.color565(0, i, i));
    t += micros() - start;
    tft.drawTriangle(cx, cy - i, cx - i, cy + i, cx + i, cy + i,
      tft.color565(i, i, 0));
  }

  return t;
}

unsigned long testRoundRects() {
  unsigned long start;
  int           w, i, i2,
                cx = tft.width()  / 2 - 1,
                cy = tft.height() / 2 - 1;

  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
  w     = min(tft.width(), tft.height());
  start = micros();
  for(i=0; i<w; i+=6) {
    i2 = i / 2;
    tft.drawRoundRect(cx-i2, cy-i2, i, i, i/8, tft.color565(i, 0, 0));
  }

  return micros() - start;
}

unsigned long testFilledRoundRects() {
  unsigned long start;
  int           i, i2,
                cx = tft.width()  / 2 - 1,
                cy = tft.height() / 2 - 1;

  tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
  start = micros();
  for(i=min(tft.width(), tft.height()); i>20; i-=6) {
    i2 = i / 2;
    tft.fillRoundRect(cx-i2, cy-i2, i, i, i/8, tft.color565(0, i, 0));
  }

  return micros() - start;
}
void setup(void) {
   Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println(F("TFT LCD test"));

  tft.reset();

  uint16_t identifier = tft.readID();
  if(identifier == 0x9325) {
    Serial.println(F("Found ILI9325 LCD driver"));
  } else if(identifier == 0x9328) {
    Serial.println(F("Found ILI9328 LCD driver"));
  } else if(identifier == 0x4535) {
    Serial.println(F("Found LGDP4535 LCD driver"));
  }else if(identifier == 0x7575) {
    Serial.println(F("Found HX8347G LCD driver"));
  } else if(identifier == 0x9595) {
    Serial.println(F("Found HX8347-I LCD driver"));
  } else if(identifier == 0x4747) {
    Serial.println(F("Found HX8347-D LCD driver"));
  } else if(identifier == 0x8347) {
    Serial.println(F("Found HX8347-A LCD driver"));
  }else if(identifier == 0x9341) {
    Serial.println(F("Found ILI9341 LCD driver"));
  }else if(identifier == 0x7783) {
    Serial.println(F("Found ST7781 LCD driver"));
  }else if(identifier == 0x8230) {
    Serial.println(F("Found UC8230 LCD driver"));  
  }else if(identifier == 0x8357) {
    Serial.println(F("Found HX8357D LCD driver"));
  } else if(identifier==0x0101){     
      identifier=0x9341;
      Serial.println(F("Found 0x9341 LCD driver"));
  }else if(identifier==0x7793){     
       Serial.println(F("Found ST7793 LCD driver"));
  }else if(identifier==0xB509){     
       Serial.println(F("Found R61509 LCD driver"));
  }else if(identifier==0x9486){     
       Serial.println(F("Found ILI9486 LCD driver"));
  }else if(identifier==0x9488){     
       Serial.println(F("Found ILI9488 LCD driver"));
  }else {
    Serial.print(F("Unknown LCD driver chip: "));
    Serial.println(identifier, HEX);
    Serial.println(F("If using the Adafruit 2.8\" TFT Arduino shield, the line:"));
    Serial.println(F("  #define USE_ADAFRUIT_SHIELD_PINOUT"));
    Serial.println(F("should appear in the library header (Adafruit_TFT.h)."));
    Serial.println(F("If using the breakout board, it should NOT be #defined!"));
    Serial.println(F("Also if using the breakout, double-check that all wiring"));
    Serial.println(F("matches the tutorial."));
    identifier=0x9486; 
  }
  tft.begin(identifier); 

  Serial.println(F("Benchmark                Time (microseconds)"));

  Serial.print(F("Screen fill              "));
  Serial.println(testFillScreen());
  delay(500);

  Serial.print(F("Text                     "));
  Serial.println(testText());
  delay(3000);

  Serial.print(F("Lines                    "));
  Serial.println(testLines(CYAN));
  delay(500);

  Serial.print(F("Horiz/Vert Lines         "));
  Serial.println(testFastLines(RED, BLUE));
  delay(500);

  Serial.print(F("Rectangles (outline)     "));
  Serial.println(testRects(GREEN));
  delay(500);

  Serial.print(F("Rectangles (filled)      "));
  Serial.println(testFilledRects(YELLOW, MAGENTA));
  delay(500);

  Serial.print(F("Circles (filled)         "));
  Serial.println(testFilledCircles(10, MAGENTA));

  Serial.print(F("Circles (outline)        "));
  Serial.println(testCircles(10, WHITE));
  delay(500);

  Serial.print(F("Triangles (outline)      "));
  Serial.println(testTriangles());
  delay(500);

  Serial.print(F("Triangles (filled)       "));
  Serial.println(testFilledTriangles());
  delay(500);

  Serial.print(F("Rounded rects (outline)  "));
  Serial.println(testRoundRects());
  delay(500);

  Serial.print(F("Rounded rects (filled)   "));
  Serial.println(testFilledRoundRects());
  delay(500);

  Serial.println(F("Done!"));
}

void loop(void) {
  for(uint8_t rotation=0; rotation<4; rotation++) {
    tft.setRotation(rotation);
    testText();
    delay(2000);
  }
}
```

Comment: You didn't show us the code in question. Please include your code in the question by editing it.

Comment: Ok, that's it added

Comment: please copy the content of the serial monitor and paste it into your post ... format it as code

Comment: ```Unknown LCD driver chip: D3D3
If using the Adafruit 2.8" TFT Arduino shield, the line:
  #define USE_ADAFRUIT_SHIELD_PINOUT
should appear in the library header (Adafruit_TFT.h).
If using the breakout board, it should NOT be #defined!
Also if using the breakout, double-check that all wiring
matches the tutorial.
Benchmark                Time (microseconds)
Screen fill              1386975
Text                     52997
```

Comment: The MCUFRIEND_kbv library has the pins hardcoded. To use the Uno pin numbering the Wemos ESP32 D1 board requires to use Dx pin names instead of x. So the library will not work with this board without changing the pins in the source code of the library.

Comment: The exact same sketch with included libraries works perfectly on my standard UNO, displays all the graphics. I need to use the ESP32 tho because it has wifi capabilities.

Comment: upvote for the use of Vogon poetry ... couldn't help myself